# Symfony-Doctrine: correct YAML syntax for default value of numeric field

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, yaml

That is a piece from my schema.yml:

```
ProductTags:
  columns:
    product_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    tag_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    discount: { type: numeric, size: 3, scale: 1, notnull: true, default: 0 }
```

but when the sql gets generated, discount field comes out with the default keyword, but no default value after it.

How can I get the right result?

Comment: I believe it's a doctrine problem, not a yaml one

Comment: I think so too. But how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Doctrine struggles with datatypes, try casting the default as a string (vs int): `default: '0'`

Comment: "numeric" is a pgSQL type. I think you need to use "float" or "decimal" for Doctrine to apply the default properly... that's at least what the Doctrine documentation seems to suggest.